# if I use Authorize then it goes to login loop does not redirect to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
   [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Login(User u)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            objlogin = new LoginClass();
            DataTable dt = objlogin.Authentication(u.Username , u.Password);
            if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                Session["UserId"] = dt.Rows[0]["UserId"];
                return RedirectToAction("Index" , "Home");
            }
            else
            {
                u.Error = "Invalid Cridential";
                return View(u);
            }
        }
        return View(u);
    }
```

Now in Homecontroller my code is like

```
[Authorize]
public class HomeController : BaseController
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

I have created BaseController is like

```
public class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        if (Session["UserId"] != null)
            base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
        else
            RedirectToAction("Login", "Login");
    }
}
```

But after successfully login it does not redirect to Homecontroller it redirect to Login action again.

Please help me .

Comment: What's the implementation of `objlogin.Authentication(...)`?  Is this a load balanced environment?

Comment: it just check user exist or not and return user data nothing else

Comment: looks like *Session["UserId"]* is being always null.

Comment: session["UserId"] is not null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by @Camilo Terevinto your `BaseController.OnActionExecuting` is not called because `Authorize` is called before with a default authorization logic that doesn't consider your custom logic with the `Session` object.

If you want to implement your own **custom authorization logic** you can do something like this:

```
public class MyAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    //Called when access is denied
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
                new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller = "Login", action = "Login" })
        );
    }
    //Core authentication, called before each action
    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var userId = httpContext.Session["UserId"];
        return userId != null;
    }
}
```

HomeController (no need to derive from custom class):

```
[MyAuthorize]
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

And your `LoginController` may be unchanged

Comment: Also [Think twice about using session state](https://brockallen.com/2012/04/07/think-twice-about-using-session-state/). It has nothing at all to do with logging into and out of the web site.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the `[Authorize]` attribute checks for the Authentication pipeline. Your login code never authenticates, it only sets a session value that will be checked on `OnActionExecuting`, which is on a lower level than the Authentication pipeline:

[image]

As you can see, first the Authentication and Authorization filters are run (where `[Authorize]` works) and then the `OnActionExecuting` code is called.

You have to either login the user to the application or use custom Action Filters and ditch the `[Authorize]` attribute completely.

Comment: So can you tell me what code should I write in BaseController to just authorize User ?

Comment: @Sagarpadhiyar That depends on your needs. You could use `FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie` or the OWIN pipeline (normally with ASP.NET Identity)

Comment: yes I understood but before any action execute I want to check on controller level that session["UserId"] is null then it redirect o Login Page. for that can you provide me little bit suggestion

Comment: @Sagarpadhiyar If you need that behavior, you'd be probably better off removing the `[Authorize]` attribute completely

Comment: Useful image. Please post the link where you got it from.

Comment: @NightOwl888 Sorry, I just googled "ASP.NET MVC pipeline", there are several hundred similar images